# How to efficiently categorise a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list as follows.

```
mylist = [["person1,person2,person3", ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]], 
          ["person4,person5,person3", ["item10", "item11", "item12"]]]
```

I want to make `person-item` list from `mylist` as follows.

```
myoutput = [["person1", [["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]]],
            ["person2", [["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]]],
            ["person3", [["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"], ["item10", "item11", "item12"]]], 
            ["person4", [["item10", "item11", "item12"]]]
            ["person5", [["item10", "item11", "item12"]]]]
```

This is how I currently do this.

```
mylist = [["person1,person2,person3", ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]], ["person4,person5,person3", ["item10", "item11", "item12"]]]

person_list = []
for item in mylist:
    person_list.extend(item[0].split(","))
person_list = list(set(person_list))
print(person_list)

myoutput = []
for person in person_list:
    mytemp = []
    for item in mylist:
        if person in item[0]:
            mytemp.append(item[1])
    myoutput.append(tuple((person, mytemp)))
print(myoutput)
```

However, this is very inefficient since I have a huge dataset to process. In other words my current program is O(n) and O(n2). I am looking for ways to efficiently do this in python.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: If your code works as intended, you may get better answers over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `dict` to add the list to the key that is the person, that would be more efficient rather than collecting the previous values each time. With `defaultdict` if the key is not present it'll add it wuth the type you specified, here a `list`, then just add your list to it

```
myoutput = defaultdict(list) # from collections import defaultdict
for item in mylist:
    for person in item[0].split(","):
        myoutput[person].append(item[1])
```

This gives

```
{'person1': [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']], 
 'person2': [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']], 
 'person3': [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'], ['item10', 'item11', 'item12']], 
 'person4': [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']], 'person5': [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]}
```

To come back to your structure if you really need it :

```
myoutput = [[k, v] for k, v in myoutput.items()]

[['person1', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']]], 
 ['person2', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']]], 
 ['person3', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'], ['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]], 
 ['person4', [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]], ['person5', [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.setdefault` to initialize each person with an empty list and keep appending incoming lists to the respective persons:

```
output = {}
for persons, items in mylist:
    for person in persons.split(','):
        output.setdefault(person, []).append(items)
```

so that:

```
list(map(list, output.items()))
```

returns:

```
[['person1', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']]],
 ['person2', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']]],
 ['person3',
  [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'],
   ['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]],
 ['person4', [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]],
 ['person5', [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [["person1,person2,person3", ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]],
          ["person4,person5,person3", ["item10", "item11", "item12"]]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in mylist:
    for name in item[0].split(','):
        d[name].append(item[1])

l = [[k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
for item in l:
    print(item)
```

Prints:

```
['person1', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']]]
['person2', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']]]
['person3', [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'], ['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]]
['person4', [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]]
['person5', [['item10', 'item11', 'item12']]]
```